# Capture a data.frame (or non-atomic) object with lazyeval

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

Is there a (preferred) way to capture a data.frame or other non-atomic object lazily using the `lazyeval` package?  It seems `lazyeval` prevents this:

```
library(lazyeval)
data(iris)
f <- function(x) lazyeval::lazy_(x, parent.frame() )
f(iris)
```

I get this error:

```
Error: is.call(expr) || is.name(expr) || is.atomic(expr) is not TRUE
```

On atomic objects this works as expected, a lazy object is returned with an unevaluated expression and the environment.

```
> f(1:10)
<lazy>
  expr: 1:10
  env:  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

### Expected output

I am pretty surprised since the docs say:

> Use lazy() like you'd use substitute() to capture an unevaluated
>   promise.

and `subsitute` can be used to capture an unevaluated *name* (getting the parent.frame is trivial):

```
> f <- function(x) substitute(x)
> f(iris)
iris      # name
```

What I would expect from lazyeval is:

```
f(iris) 
<lazy>
  expr: iris
  env:  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

I am likely missing something?  Help?

### Relevant Info

```
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)"

> packageVersion('lazyeval')
[1] 0.1.10.9000
```

### Update

@MrFlick has a decent pair of answers (see below), but neither produce the expected output:

```
> f <- function(x) lazyeval::lazy(x,parent.frame())
> f(iris)
<lazy>
  expr: structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6,  ...
  env:  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

This stores the iris in `expr`; only the name is desired.

```
> f <- function(x) lazyeval::lazy_( quote(x), parent.frame() )
> f(iris)
<lazy>
  expr: x
  env:  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

This capture the right `env`, but the wrong expression.

### Answer

Inpsired by @MrFlick, this seems to work, but it requires an additional `subtitute` to make it work correctly.  I am not entirely sure why, however:

```
f <- function(x) lazyeval::lazy_( substitute(x), parent.frame() )
f(iris)
f(1:10)
a = 1:5
f(a)
```

Comment: When you use `substitute`, you just get an unevaluated call, so that `iris` wasn't really the `iris`-named object in your workspace. It was just a symbol with no "effort" yet made to match it to an object.

Comment: I realize that.  What it does give me is a name object that can be evaluated in another frame. To also capture the enclosing environment is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inpsired by @MrFlick, this seems to work, but it requires an additional subtitute to make it work correctly. I am not entirely sure why, however:

```
f <- function(x) lazyeval::lazy_( substitute(x), parent.frame() )
f(iris)
f(1:10)
a = 1:5
f(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

`lazy()` and `lazy_()` are slight different functions. I think you want either

```
f <- function(x) lazyeval::lazy(x, parent.frame())
```

or

```
f <- function(x) lazyeval::lazy_(quote(x), environment())
```

Note the  `lazy_()` function needs the quoted name while `lazy()` does the quoting for you. Also note we use the function environment for the `lazy_` call since that's where `x` is defined.